# Drupal Webform missing edit link for fields from CiviCRM database

Tags: webform-civicrm

Webform Form Components page does not show option to edit individual fields that are from CiviCRM database. Drupal fields work OK.  This was working previously but is not working after upgrading versions.   I have multiple instances and some forms show edit option and others do not.

Answer (score 3):

Version incompatibility introduced in Webform version 7.x-4.12 and webform civicrm 7.x-4.13.

Upgrade webform civicrm to 7.x-4.14 solves problem.

Drupal issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2600878 details this.